# Sharing Listview in flutter?

Tags: flutter, flutter-layout, flutter-dependencies, mobile-application, dart-pub

I am new to flutter. I have a scrollable list to share via WhatsApp or mail. So, How can I share this List as Image or Text? Or is there any way to share the entire page(Scrollable) as an image or text? suggest methods to do this.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can create a String of your data shown in the list and share it via the Share Package.

Share Package: https://pub.dev/packages/share

Exapmle:

```
Share.share('Here insert your created String');
```

After running this line of code it opens the share screen of your phone and you can choose if you want to share it via WhatsApp or so.

Edit: Creating a List inside a String

```
String list = '';
itemList.forEach((item) {
    if(item.isChecked) {
        list += '-';
        list += item.title;
        list += '\n';
    }
});
```

Comment: Thanks for the quick response @Ruben Rohner.. But I want to share the full list of items. Is it possible to share?

Comment: Yes sure you can do that with the full list of items. Just make a String for every item and join them together to one String that you then share.

Comment: I think then it comes as a paragraph right! How could I get the output as a list type too?

Comment: With "\n" you can create a new Line in the String and then at every start of a line put a "-"

Comment: Thank you @Ruben Rohner

Comment: Rohner. In my case the list items are completely user defined. Like I create a list Items with checkbox. Whatever user checks that need to be share, So, now I can't manually add text over share option. How can I do this?

Comment: First you create an empty String. Than you iterate through your list and check for each item if its checkbox is checked. If so you add this item to the String. After iterating through the whole list you share the String

Comment: Can you please provide an example to add strings to string in the list format. Update answer with an example @Ruben Rohner

Comment: Rohner Thank you so much